# Backing up Google Drive files to a file on a USB key

Tags: backup, usb, google-drive, google-backup

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone.

I would like to back up my Google Drive files in their entirety to my USB key.

How can I do this from the Google Drive app, if possible.

If not how can I do this (and can I do it all quicky, and in one go (perhaps even by issuing a command in Google that produces a backup)?

Thanks.

Comment: You have two options 1. Manually select each folder/item in Drive and download to USB 2. Use an app like [folder sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) to sync your drive on schedule or on demand